# Am i doing enough to protect a php logged in session?

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

I have an application which grants a user access to view a list of entries. a logged in session gets a session cookie (naturally) and uses this cookie to view results. the results are formatted in the URL like so `/admin.php?page=12&results=5` where results are the number of entries to show per page and page is the page they are currently viewing. I want to know if I am doing enough to make sure that no one has hijacked my logged in a cookie in order to get the sensitive data.

[1] CORS headers deny all csrf
[2] session id regenerated every 5 minutes and shuts down gracefully logging all access to invalidated sessions, logging both new session user and the last user of old session accessed.
[3] ensuring cookie is ok against replay attacks

Is there anything else?

Answer (score -2):

Hi seems like you are using a "GET" request to pass data. Please use a "POST" request it is more secure and the details will not available in the URL. (Because sensitive data must not visible to others)

Comment: POST is no more secure than GET

Comment: POST is not more secure than GET in any way. Security through obscurity is not security.

Comment: There is no magic POST security. Don't give somebody the false hope.

Comment: POST is more secure than GET for a couple of reasons.

GET parameters are passed via URL. This means that parameters are stored in server logs, and browser history. When using GET, it makes it very easy to alter the data being submitted the the server as well, as it is right there in the address bar to play with.

Comment: The problem when comparing security between the two is that POST may deter the casual user, but will do nothing to stop someone with malicious intent. It is very easy to fake POST requests, and shouldn't be trusted outright.

The biggest security issue with GET is not malicious intent of the end-user, but by a third party sending a link to the end-user. I cannot email you a link that will force a POST request, but I most certainly can send you a link with a malicious GET request. I.E:

Comment: Please check this link  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33837/get-vs-post-which-is-more-secure

Comment: Brian You are right but it is somewhat better than GET